# AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified

Tags: apache-http-server, macbook

I am using a MacBook Pro. I am trying to find out why my localhost is not working. it keep returning this message;

I ran a Apache configation test:

**apachectl configtest**

```
H00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I suspect that this error occurred because I used brew to install several versions of PHP.

I understand that I need to edit my Apache config file with this. I ran following command to find out which Apache file is being used:

`apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES`

but this returns the following:

```
Included configuration files:
  (*) /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
    (499) /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
    (505) /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
    (545) /private/etc/apache2/other/php7.conf
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for endys-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

I also use

`which -a  apachectl`

this returned:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

I tried this:

`sudo vi /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

then added:

`ServerName localhost`

but this returned this message:

```
"/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
"/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I am now unclear which config file I should change and how I can go about locating it.

**EDIT:**

I also checked my config file to see if its listening to port 80. This is the settings in the file:

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
<IfDefine SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 8080
</IfDefine>
<IfDefine !SERVER_APP_HAS_DEFAULT_PORTS>
    Listen 80
</IfDefine>
```

Comment: I suspect that your /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf is not setup correctly, or there's no valid vhost file is using those. The error about the FQDN is related to not having Servername variable setup (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername). Is there an example-httpd.conf or similar in the extra folder? (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: hello @Smock . thanks for replying. i am new to this. can you please describe to me what i should do to fix it. would really be grateful if you gave example code. thanks

Comment: Have a look in your httpd.conf for a 'Listen' directive - it might be commented out try setting it like this: Listen 80

Comment: @Smock i checked and its listening to port 80. i have edited my question to show the response

Answer (score 1):

> I am now unclear which config file I should change and how I can go about locating it.

Your `apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES` command seems to clearly list `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` as the primary configuration file for Apache in this instance. Try adding e.g. `ServerName localhost` to that file.

Comment: In some of the configuration setup examples for mac, this line may have been left out. Simple fix!